# How to pass id to componentdidmount in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have function, I want to pass ID to componentDidMount. I tried hard but didn't find any solution to achieve my goal . Actually I have renderEvent() function , In this function I have customerID , I want to use this ID in componentdidmount for API Calling . could some one please help me how to solve this problem

**Code**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    .../ want to access CustomerID here 
  }


renderEvent() {
 <p>Customer Name : {slotInfo.customerId}
}
```

want to send this customerID to up componentdidmount function

Comment: you can't do it like that, pass the data via component props instead

Comment: Where does `slotInfo` come from? Show more code.

Comment: can't you just create a `get` method for `customerId` and call that method in  `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @chumakoff you can please pass just cusomterId , leave slotinfo

Comment: @PrabhatMishra can you please write code for me , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here it is,but the further code will depend on ,from where you get `slotInfo.`

```
componentDidMount() {
    const custId = getCustomerId()
}

getCustomerId=()=> slotInfo.customerId

renderEvent() {
    return 
 <p>Customer Name : {getCustomerId()}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component should be rendered like this:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.slotInfo); // Here you can access your prop.
    }

    render() {
          const { slotInfo } = this.props;

          return <p>Customer Name: {slotInfo.customerName}</p>;
    }
}

class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Component slotInfo={{ customerName: 'Bob' }} />;
    }
}
```

This way you can access the prop wherever you want. Currently, I can't tell how you are loading the data. But this is how you should be doing it.

Comment: I don't want to include two components, I just want to pass id to componentdidmount .

Comment: Only other 'good' option is saving it into the state by using this.setState();

Answer (score 0):

If the if is provided by a father component you could retrieve that id from properties:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.custId = this.props.customerId;
}

renderEvent() {
    return 
 <p>Customer Name : {this.custId}
}
```

or better from the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.custId =props.customerId;
}

renderEvent() {
    return <p>Customer Name : {this.custId}
}
```

the code above use flat properties, but you could pass you slotInfo obj